# VBA Excel: Delete worksheet when it has a certain name

Tags: excel, vba

For my workbook, when a user wants to delete tabs for a project, they put the PRJNumber in cell T14 of the program tab. There are various other tabs with that project number as the last 6 digits of the name (e.g., A_PRJNumber, B_PRJNumber, etc). All PRJNumbers are 6 digits long. The code below should work, the two msgboxes indicate that it is reading both the 6 digits in cell T14 and in the tab name correctly, but it does not delete the tab or give me any errors. Ideas?

```
Sub Delete_Project()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim PRJNumber
 PRJNumber = Sheets("Program").Range("T14").Value
 MsgBox (PRJNumber)

 For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 MsgBox (Right(wks.Name, 6))
    If Right(wks.Name, 6) = PRJNumber Then
        wks.Delete
    End If


 Next wks

End Sub
```

Comment: Make the second message box do this: `MsgBox (Right(wks.Name, 6) = PRJNumber)`. Does it say `True` or `False`?

Comment: What I'm suspecting is that T14 contains some extra spaces/etc.  `MsgBox "Hello  "` would look the same as `MsgBox "Hello"` but the values are not the same.

Comment: You could do `PRJNumber = Trim(Sheets("Program").Range("T14"))` and that should resolve it I think.

Comment: The trim fixed it!!!! Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm suspecting is that T14 contains some extra spaces/etc.

For example:

```
Dim str1 as String, str2 as String
str1 = "123456  "
str2 = "123456"

'## These two message boxes should look the same, you would not be able to tell the difference:
MsgBox str1 

MsgBox str2

'## But by comparing their inputs, you can see they are NOT the same
MsgBox str1 = str2
```

If this is the case, then you can use the `TRIM` function which will take care of user-error if they inadvertently enter spaces (often these are result of copy/paste from other applications, etc.):

```
PRJNumber = Trim(Sheets("Program").Range("T14"))
```